# Switching to redux, where do I register my global eventListener for a dropdown

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have two functions in my Component:

```
openMenu = () => {
  this.setState({menuOpen: true})
  document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu)
}

closeMenu = () => {
  this.setState({menuOpen: false})
  document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu)
}
```

This opens a dropdown and closes it when I click anywhere else. How do I implement this with redux? Handling `state` is no problem, but what about the `click` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly implemented your custom event listener with the correct addEventListener and the corresponding removeEventListener.

May be, according to me I would put the addEventListener inside componentDidMount and the removeEventListener into componentWillUnmount

Comment: Thanks, great suggestion.